# Can a Pakistani with a US permanent resident card exit Heathrow, London during a 13hr layover?

Tags: layovers, london, lhr, pakistani-citizens

I am traveling to Pakistan from Washington DC and have about 13 hours of stay in London Heathrow on both outbound and inbound trips. I have a passport from Pakistan but a PR card from the US that was issued after 1998 requirements. I think I can visit London i.e. go out of the airport and come back.

Is this so?